# How to do join on 3 tables in Django Rest Framework (only primary keys)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models, each with a primary key. How can I perform join operation using rest framework in Django?

These are tables:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: please include those models in the question?

Comment: what are you trying to query out of these three models?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible? Or can you suggest some other ways how can I perform join on any models in django rest framework.

Comment: What is your joining criteria?

for example: `do you need all the books from an author(s)? OR all the books from a specific publisher? OR all the books in a database with their authors and publishers? OR something else?` .. Trying to get your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

there are really good examples here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

This page explains how you can include the authors names when serializing book,
and also how to easily include a list of books when serializing the author.

If you want to be able to provide an API for publisher, you can easily provide a list of books using the methods in the link above.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations